# How can I adjust render settings on a scene being linked into a new project?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, workflow, linked-data

I'm working on developing a usable Blender pipeline for a project that my company is working on and have run into an issue with scene links. I'm not sure if it's a bug, if it's intentional, or if I'm just missing something - but I can't find a good solution through standard research methods.

The situation: Multiple consecutive shots in a sequence (for television) are receiving some CG props that we're making and animating in Blender. Since all of the shots are comprised of only two angles, we would like to be able to create .blend files for each shot that's linking in the model assets as well as the "master" world (HDR lighting) and render settings. Objects, groups, and worlds behave accordingly when linked, but when I link the master scene into the new project to take advantage of copied render nodes (which are extensive) and general Cycles settings, the project is completely locked with no option to make local.

This puts us in a jam, since we need to modify specific render settings like in/out frames, File Output directories, etc, but we DO want to be able to control a majority of the settings from one master project.

In case it wasn't clear, this is the setup that we're ideally going for. Each (#) is a separate .blend file:

-

(1) Model/Shading/Texture (2) Rigging (3) World/Render Setup

(4) "Final" project for animation which is linking in (1), (2), and (3).

-

Is there any way around this? I've even tried going in through the text editor for manual adjustments, but it can't be accessed from the locked scene link.